# Increasing divs height when dynamically adding content

Tags: css, ajax

Right now my webapplication will dynamically add content via ajax, and then slide down. It's normally got two divs on either side with height: 100%, and a repeating image so as to be a border. When the content gets added however, the borders don't extend down along with it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ajax "success" function, after adding your content, read in the new height of the main content area, then set the height of the two border divs to that height.